# Why isn't Warden using all of the default strategies?

Tags: authentication, warden

I'm migrating a Rails 3.2 app to greener (higher numbered) pastures. AuthLogic, which served me well forever, apparently doesn't work in 4. So I'm transitioning to Warden.

The warden.rb file below has been migrated from an app written a few years ago ... but the warden docs suggest that the basic interface is the same. Feels like it should work.

I have two authentication strategies, :httpauth and :params. The :params strategy works. Here's a logfile entry showing authentication working:

```
Started POST "/user_sessions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-08-17 16:32:12 -0500
Processing by UserSessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "username"=>"...."}
[AUTH] checking params
[AUTH] Authenticating user jw@mustmodify.com from params
...
[AUTH] User jw@mustmodify.com authenticated with a password.
...
Completed 302 Found in 111.5ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

However, when using httpauth (via curl):

```
curl http://dev.projectdomain.com/clouds/bmi.svg -u user:password
```

I'm expecting to see "checking httpauth" then "checking params" ... but instead I see "checking params" twice. I assume I'm asking warden to authenticate twice in the controller... But according to my understanding, I should also be seeing "checking httpauth". Any thoughts about why that isn't working?

```
Started GET "/clouds/bmi.svg" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-08-17 16:22:51 -0500
Processing by CloudsController#show as SVG
  Parameters: {"id"=>"bmi"}
[AUTH] checking params
[AUTH] checking params
```

and then that's the end of authentication.

Here's my config/initializers/warden.rb file. One note... since httpauth and params use the same fields and methods to authenticate, I abstracted the "checking of passwords" stuff to a single class: UserCredentialAuthentication. I actually have a third strategy, :token, but it isn't a default strategy and I have excluded it for simplicity. I did verify that the problem still exists with the code as amended:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use Warden::Manager do |manager|
  manager.default_strategies :httpauth, :params
end

Warden::Manager.serialize_into_session do |user|
  user.persistence_token
end

Warden::Manager.serialize_from_session do |id|
  User.where(persistence_token: id).first
end

class UserCredentialAuthentication < ::Warden::Strategies::Base
  def verify_against_old_credentials( user, password )
    Sha512.matches?( user.sha512_password, password, user.sha512_salt )
  end

  def transition_from_sha512!( user, password )
    user.password = password
    user.sha512_password = nil
    user.sha512_salt = nil
    user.save
  end

  def authenticate!
    Rails.logger.warn("[AUTH] Authenticating user #{username} from #{medium}")
    user = User.find_by_username_or_email(username)

    if user.blank?
      Rails.logger.warn("[AUTH] No Such User")
      fail "Invalid email or password"

    elsif user.sha512_password.not.blank? && verify_against_old_credentials( user, password )
      Rails.logger.warn("[AUTH] User #{user.email} authenticated with a SHA512 password.")
      transition_from_sha512!( user, password )
      success! user

    elsif user.password_digest && user.authenticate( password )
      Rails.logger.warn("[AUTH] User #{user.email} authenticated with a password.")
      success! user

    else
      Rails.logger.warn("[AUTH] Bad Password")
      fail "Invalid email or password"

    end
  end
end


Warden::Strategies.add(:httpauth, UserCredentialAuthentication) do
  def medium
    'httpAuth'
  end

  def valid?
    Rails.logger.warn("[AUTH] checking httpAuth")
    auth.provided? && auth.basic?
  end

  def auth
    @auth ||= Rack::Auth::Basic::Request.new(env)
  end

  def username
    auth.credentials[1]
  end

  def password
    auth.credentials[2]
  end
end

Warden::Strategies.add(:params, UserCredentialAuthentication) do
  def medium
    'params'
  end

  def valid?
    Rails.logger.warn("[AUTH] checking params")
    credential_params['username'] && credential_params['password']
  end

  def username
    credential_params['username']
  end

  def password
    credential_params['password']
  end

  def credential_params
    p = params.blank? ? post_params : params
    p['user_session'] || {}
  end

  def post_params
    @post_params ||= get_post_params
  end

  def get_post_params
    req = Rack::Request.new(env)

    if( req.post? )
      begin
        body = req.body.read
        req.body.rewind
        JSON.parse( body )
      end
    else
      {}
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that two strategies that inherit from the same base class look like the same strategy to Warden. I copy/pasted, fixed a small error in my httpauth strategy, and it worked. Unfortunate.

I used a module instead of a class to abstract the common methods. Final solution:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use Warden::Manager do |manager|
  manager.default_strategies [:httpauth, :params]
end

Warden::Manager.serialize_into_session do |user|
  user.persistence_token
end

Warden::Manager.serialize_from_session do |id|
  User.where(persistence_token: id).first
end

module UserCredentialAuthentication
  def verify_against_old_credentials( user, password )
    Sha512.matches?( user.sha512_password, password, user.sha512_salt )
  end

  def transition_from_sha512!( user, password )
    user.password = password
    user.sha512_password = nil
    user.sha512_salt = nil
    user.save
  end

  def authenticate!
    Rails.logger.warn("[AUTH] Authenticating user #{username} from #{medium}")
    user = User.find_by_username_or_email(username)

    if user.blank?
      Rails.logger.warn("[AUTH] No Such User")
      fail "Invalid email or password"

    elsif user.sha512_password.not.blank? && verify_against_old_credentials( user, password )
      Rails.logger.warn("[AUTH] User #{user.email} authenticated with a SHA512 password.")
      transition_from_sha512!( user, password )
      success! user

    elsif user.password_digest && user.authenticate( password )
      Rails.logger.warn("[AUTH] User #{user.email} authenticated with a password.")
      success! user

    else
      Rails.logger.warn("[AUTH] Bad Password")
      fail "Invalid email or password"

    end
  end
end


Warden::Strategies.add(:httpauth) do
  include UserCredentialAuthentication

  def medium
    'httpAuth'
  end

  def valid?
    Rails.logger.warn("[AUTH] checking httpAuth")
    auth.provided? && auth.basic?
  end

  def username
    auth.credentials[0]
  end

  def password
    auth.credentials[1]
  end

  def auth
    @auth ||= Rack::Auth::Basic::Request.new(env)
  end
end

Warden::Strategies.add(:params) do
  include UserCredentialAuthentication

  def medium
    'params'
  end

  def valid?
    Rails.logger.warn("[AUTH] checking params")
    credential_params['username'] && credential_params['password']
  end

  def username
    credential_params['username']
  end

  def password
    credential_params['password']
  end

  def credential_params
    p = params.blank? ? post_params : params
    p['user_session'] || {}
  end

  def post_params
    @post_params ||= get_post_params
  end

  def get_post_params
    if( request.post? )
      begin
        body = request.body.read
        request.body.rewind
        JSON.parse( body )
      end
    else
      {}
    end
  end
end
```